# Sync problems between entity object on Hibernate 3 and struts

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I work at a complex web application that use EJB and Hibernate on JBoss. I use singleton EntityManagerFactory, and share it between all running process using Entity Manager instance.

The problem occurs when in a struct action is called an update on entity, and before action ends another process read and update same object.
I have that second process (it's a web service called from third-parts) read an old value and not the updated one in the action.

I know that data become persistent on database only after action end its work and control come back to user. Unfortunately this action after Entity Manager merge execution, it must call a web service that sometimes return after 10s . Meanwhile other process have wrong value if read this object.

I need that merge in first process become instantly persistent, or, I need that other process read right value. 
I don't know if the second level cache is working and has effect in this scenario.

A solution is to make an update using JDBC instead Hibernate, but I would like a clean solution to do it.

a brief outline

```
t0 = start action   ;t1= action find and merge entity; t2= start call to web service; t6= web service return; tend = end action  ; 
t3= start second process ; t4= find and merge entity; t5=end second process

t0             t1        t2    t3    t4  t5            t6        tend

|---------------|--------|------------------------------|-------|

                               |-----|----|
```

I need that at t3 the value read is that one merged at t2.

This is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ApplicationWeb_EJB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/ds/VisiaIntegrazioneDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>.....entity.ApplicationServer</class>
    ....
    <class>.....entity.Devices</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
      <!-- Caching properties -->
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />-->
      <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="ehcache.xml"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>-->
      <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />-->
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4"/>
    <!-- hibernate.generate_statistics a true produce informazioni su hibernate da loggare -->
      <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/> 

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

this is an example of Entity Manager update

```
EntityManager em = EntityMan.getEMF().createEntityManager();

        try {

            em.find(Devices.class, device.getId());
            em.merge(device);
            em.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I don't know precisely how your application is configured, but you probably should be able to see the changes made to the db after the EJB method (if it runs under CMT transaction) returns. Perhaps the call to the WS (the one which lasts up to 10 sec) is made from within the EJB method and this is what delays the transaction commit? If yes, is it possible (by the application logic) to refactor the code so that the WS call takes place outside of the EJB method?

Comment: Flush in T1 and set T2 to transaction isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED

Comment: Alan Hay's solution should be the easiest. Another approach is to try and somehow make sure that the remote request that comes in the middle uses the same EntityManager object. That however is a whole other can of worms, when it comes to determining which one and making sure you don't close it too early, but you still close it.

Comment: @JohnDonn yes, the web service call is made in a struct action, in this action I have a call to ejb method that use Entity Manager for read/write values from db, and then a call to a web service that some times can return after several seconds. Only after action ends and the control return to user, I can see data updated on database. Meanwhile other process read stale data, and not that one updated from ejb call.

Comment: "I know that data become persistent on database only after action end its work and control come back to user." - this seems to me the strange part. You actually debugged the code, and saw that after EJB method returns (before the long WS call), an **external** MySQL client shows that the data was not modified? If so, since it seems strange to me that the transaction commits when Action.execute() returns, perhaps it is after the long call to the WS that you see the changes? And in such case, what does this long call do?

Comment: "I don't know if the second level cache is working and has effect in this scenario." - from the configuration it seems that not only the second level cache is enabled, but also the query cache is enabled, and yes, this might play a role in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, after ejb code - em.merge(device);  em.flush(); - I can see old value using MySQL client, I see changes only after web action end.  The long web service call make an update on a remote device. I read somewhere that the transaction end when web action end, it is not so?

Comment: "Yes, after ejb code - em.merge(device); em.flush(); - I can see old value using MySQL client" - no, after em.flush() it is expected that you won't see anything, as the transaction is not yet committed. You should put a breakpoint immediately **after** the EJB method call, inside the Struts action, and **then** check with MySQL client what is that you see inside the db. "I read somewhere that the transaction end when web action end" - no, the default would be transactions which are started when you enter an EJB method call, and are committed when that call returns. Not when action returns.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out the whole process, so the statements I am reporting below are probably based on a wrong picture.

If I understood correctly, you would have problem even if the web service took 10ms. A request could come in the middle in any case.

But, am I wrong in saying that are you creating the entity manager, rather having injected by the container ? If you share the same manager within all your singleton methods, you can have more control on the cache concurrency access.

Second, if the call to the web service is not mandatory for the final value, is there a particular reason why you are not invoking the web service asynchronously, with a message driven bean or by using `@Asynchronous` annotation ?

**[UPDATE]** You cannot have a real time concurrent access application that rely on a 10sec WS response.

For example, if the last step WS call fail, what do you do ? Rollback ? So, what if the new incoming client has read uncommitted data that you later are going to roll back ?

As some other have probably said, make the last WS call asynchronous, or better delegate to a message driven bean (which has the advantage of retry the WS call in case of failure). In either way the call is returned immediately to the client.

But I am quite confident that you will have the same problem again. If I understood the architecture correctly I would revisit the design to do this things:

1. Invoke the WS asynchronously or with MDB in order to return call to the client
2. Make calls to the entity manager, at least the one that insist on the same table, to be thread safe. Should be easy, because you have a singleton class

Comment: the service took 10s not 10 ms, and I need response to continue with business logic. I have a singleton class for allocate a EntityManagerFactory, then share this instance between all processes that needs to read/write from database.